# R Shiny Dashboard, change color for all hyperlinks

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I've created some valueboxes with hyperlinks to different tabs within the app.

ui

```
tags$script(HTML("
    var openTab = function(tabName){
                 $('a', $('.sidebar')).each(function() {
                 if(this.getAttribute('data-value') == tabName) {
                 this.click()
                 };
                 });
                 }
                 "))
```

server

```
  output$tplot <- renderValueBox({
     valueBox(
     paste0(sum(rowSums(x)>0)),
     tags$p(a("Total", onclick = "openTab('metrics')", href="#"), 
     style = "color: white;"), 
     icon = icon("boxes"),
     color = "navy")
  })
```

It works great, but the hyperlinks are always in a steelblue color and it limits my choice of readable colors for the valuebox.

Is there a way to change the hyperlink color?  Is there a way to set the hyperlink color globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyperlinks have tag `<a>`. You can globally change hyperlink color by applying css to that tag. Here's minimal example -

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML("a {color: red}"))),
    tags$a("click here"),
    br(),
    tags$a("click here as well")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

  }
)
```